# send email notification when a puppet run fails

Tags: puppet

I'm using open source puppet version 3.8 to control my environment in AWS.
I was wondering if there is good way to monitor puppet agents failures. 
basically, I would like to get notified by email each time a puppet run fails (for each node).
is there a way to achieve this functionality in the open source version of puppet?

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recomend the tagmail module for this: https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/tagmail

"Puppet's loglevels (debug, info, notice, warning, err, alert, emerg, crit, and verbose) can also be used as tags, and the all tag always matches every log message."

You could also setup to tag on particular resources or classes, depending on when you want the error messages to show.